# Capacitance through a diode

Tags: capacitor, diodes, circuit-design, voltage-regulator

As I was designing power circuit, I have a place where two power rails come together with Schottky diodes (power from battery vs power from charger,) similar to what you can find in phones or laptops.

The lines come together and then they go into buck-boost IC which regulates my power rail. Like any other respectable switching voltage regulator IC, it required input capacitance.

I caught myself thinking: a capacitor can be before a Schottky or after. I don't want to discuss where specifically I need to put the capacitor in my situation, obviously, the chip wants it as close to its input pins as possible with no components in between, but this situation made me think about the behavior of this stuff in general.

How does capacitor before a (Schottky/normal/etc) diode affect the line after the diode? Meaning, how much does the capacitance before the diode affect the capacitance of the line after the diode (we're talking about power line here, but if there is something interesting to say about other cases, feel free to do that - better have too much info than too little).

While we're at it, how does a capacitor after diode affect the line before the diode?

[image]

I don't think I will run into any trouble with my device because of this, I carefully pick components and carefully design circuits to avoid questionable moments, the question is more for general knowledge and understanding. Besides, you never know when some principles behind it may be useful somewhere else.

Comment: *similar to what can find in phones or laptops* I would not expect that as even a schottky diode has a forward voltage drop. What is usually used are MOSFETs as that can result in a much lower voltage drop.

Comment: *capacitor can be before schottky or after.* What capacitor? The smoothing capacitor? I would expect the smoothing cap. **before** the diode as otherwise the diode coudl switch on/of with the unsmoothed input voltage (from a bridge rectifier for example). You need to add more details and the rest of the circuit because at this moment the question is too vague.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie okay, more specifically: the line is a power rail. If there is no diode, then the capacitor, well, just adds capacitance to the line. But if there is diode, things become not so obvious. For example, if there is voltage dip after the diode, the cap will obviously be able to discharge there to compensate for it, but it won't be able to compensate for a positive voltage spike (in case consumption momentarily drops for example). I was looking to expand this logic further, if possible

Comment: *more specifically: the line is a power rail* My text to circuit translator is broken so you'll have to draw a schematic. And as mentioned already: more context, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie there is no more context, the circuit is drawn above. If this isn't enough, nobody forces you to reply, no hard feelings. Somebody else will understand what I mean. Or not, and then I will have to look for my answers elsewhere, and it's ok.

Comment: *nobody forces you to reply* No, but think about how helpful this site would be if all the questions are unclear, incomplete without the required details. There would be a lot of guessing and misunderstandings. That will only create more confusion and no helpful answers.